# How to stop android phone from vibrate during the start up and the shut down?

Tags: 2.2-froyo

When one turn on the phone or switch off the phone, the android phone will make a single vibration.

I don't know whether if the phone is telling me that - Good Morning or Good Bye by using vibration, but what I would like to know if it is possible to set it to stop vibrate when I either switch on or switch off the phone?

Using Froyo Android. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't something that can't be turned on or off.  It's possible that it's a vendor specific thing, you don't say what device you have or if you are rooted or not, so I assume this is the case.

I'm running a SGS3 with a custom ROM on it (AOKP) and I've just restarted the device and can confirm there was no vibration during the start or stop procedure.  However my Nexus One with a stock ROM did vibrate.

A possible fix is to root the device and stick a custom ROM on there, but that's quite an extreme fix for the issue.